# How can i trigger an azure monitoring alert manually?

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I want to trigger the alerts that i have configured for a system manually, we don't have access to the infrastructural design of the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Azure Monitor only allows you to manually create alerts that will notify you when a metric crosses a predefined threshold.
- you’ll be able to add a condition to trigger the alert and can set the threshold you’d like to alert on but we cannot trigger an azure monitoring alert manually.